# java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 when adding servlet

Tags: java, servlets, swagger

I am using Java 7. I am adding Swagger by following [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-RESTEasy-2.X-Project-Setup-1.5#adding-the-dependencies-to-your-application).

So I added the following servlet:

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey2Config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>api.version</param-name>
        <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
        <param-value>https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Now when I start the server:

**Error**

> 16:34:57,003 ERROR [org.jboss.as.deployment]
> (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"Composite operation failed and was
> rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"Failed
> services" =>
> {"jboss.deployment.unit."corporateEAR-3.10.ear".WeldService" =>
> "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
> jboss.deployment.unit."corporateEAR-3.10.ear".WeldService:
> com.google.common.collect.ComputationException:
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3"}}}}

I think it is related to:

```
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
```

**Question**

Anyone know how to fix this? Do I need to add somewhere else because I have added a servlet?

**More info:**

I do have the a project with a hierarchy of maven poms, and this web.xml is a child module. A different child module has:

```
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

The child module where I made the change had:

```
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
```

And I added:

```
<load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the error to go away, I changed the `swagger-jaxrs` version.

**pm.xml**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

To

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```